# PhpStorm: Comment shortcut places slashes at beginning of line

Tags: comments, phpstorm

When I use the comment shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl + /</kbd>) the slashes are placed at the beginning of the line, like this:

```
protected function before()
{
//    echo "(before) ";  
}
```

However I'd expect this behaviour:

```
protected function before()
{
    //echo "(before) ";  
}
```

How do I configure PhpStorm to use the latter approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Code Style | PHP`
3. `Other` tab and uncheck `Line comments at first column` option

[image]

---

In modern versions it is now located at the `Code Generation` tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i didnt expect it to be at the "Other" tab. :)

Comment: it is now in the "Code Generation" tab

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm 2018.3 and newer:

1. File -> Settings (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + S</kbd>)
2. Editor -> Code Style -> PHP
3. (tab) Code Generation -> Comment Code -> (uncheck) Line comment at first column